# Set 410 list of url with space

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have list of url with space on it , And i want to set them as gone (410)

```
https://www.website.com/Enhanced Category/religions/page/28
https://www.website.com/Enhanced Category/
```

Im on shared hosting using litespeed server...tried to encode the space on my htaccess

```
https://www.website.com/Enhanced%20Category/religions/page/28
https://www.website.com/Enhanced%20Category/
```

but it failed, the url still serve as 404...can anyone help me?

My htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 410 /Enhanced%20Category
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/([\w-]+\.html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
<Files xmlrpc.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
Options All -Indexes
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Requested url

```
   https://www.website.com/Enhanced Category return 404 status
   https://www.website.com/Enhanced%20Category return 410 status
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Comment: ok, i've updated my question

Comment: _“tried to encode the space on my htaccess”_ - where? I don’t see anything in the .htaccess content you have shown. Or any place where you would respond with a 410 status code either.

Comment: @YudiAnto, Also you have 2 sections of `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`? you can have all in this section.

Comment: i remove it since it not works

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs, fair warning haven't tested full htaccess file since there are other rules mentioned by OP with my added ones.

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/([\w-]+\.html)$ /$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^Enhanced%20Category/religions/page/28/?$ - [R=401,L]
RewriteRule ^Enhanced Category/?$ - [R=401,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: still 404 (not works) but accessing https://www.website.com/Enhanced%20Category does return 410

Comment: @YudiAnto, sorry I didn't get, you have asked here for `401` error hence I edited rules as per that, kindly do provide more details which sample/example url is NOT working and which is working(because as per your question if 401 code is getting returned then we should be good here correct?), thank you.

Comment: when requested encoded url its work (Redirect 410 /Enhanced%20Category) but without encoded space it doesnt...thanks anyway

Comment: @YudiAnto, could you please try my edited rules and let me know if these help you now?